# 4-20mA to switching output

Tags: transistors, switching-regulator, 4-20ma

I have a 4-20mA output. I need to turn an LED on when let's say 20mA is reached. I can obviously do this easily with a plc or an Arduino, but I need to do it as cheaply as possible. Is there a simpler way to do this? Can I achieve this with a BJT?

Comment: Not on its own you can't.

Comment: Are you have external power for your circuit, or you want to get power from loop?

Comment: What other things are in your circuit? If you've already have an opamp, for example, for basically no extra money you can get multiple opamps in one package. I *bet* the solution with the best ease/cost tradeoff depends on doing something that your circuit needs anyway. What's the voltage source for your 4-20 mA loop?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a BJT turn on at a relatively well-defined current through a base-emitter resistor.

Let's say you choose a 12 mA (halfway between 4 and 20) threshold. We want about 700 mV at that current, which needs a resistor of 700/12 = 58 ohms, 56 is the nearest preferred value. Most general purpose BJTs will be capable of sinking the balance of 8 mA through their BE junction with no problem.

Now whether you can permit the 4-20 mA loop to be connected to your LED and power supply is another matter. If one or the other is known to be isolated, then there's no problem.

An alternative is to use the current loop to turn on an opto-isolator. Most use an IR LED at the input, with a forward voltage of about 1.3 V. A resistor of 100 ohms is then about the right value. Your opto will need sufficient current gain to light your LED directly from its output.

Comment: Yes that would work. an optocoupler can switch the LED circuit. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

The really simple circuit that Neil is first talking about looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXTYOJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(The above assumes that you have a \$5\:\text{V}\$ voltage source.)

As mentioned, it will begin to turn on at around \$12\:\text{mA}\$ and be fully on after \$14\:\text{mA}\$, or so. So this works pretty well and is very cheap to make and test. But it galvanically connects the \$4\:\text{mA}\to20\:\text{mA}\$ source to your LED power source and this may not be acceptable. It also lacks hysteresis.

For an opto-isolated output, you could consider the [6N137](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84732/6n137.pdf):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAwCyy.png)</sup>

(Again, the above assumes that you have a \$5\:\text{V}\$ voltage source. In fact, in this case you can't use a voltage source that is much different -- see datasheet linked above.)